# Cannot update Coral SW on Raspbery Pi

Tags: google-coral

When I try to update mit Raspberry Pi with "sudo upt update" I got an error for " https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt coral-edgetpu-stable InRelease [6.722 B]" that there is no public key for my signature. Who knows how to fix this?

Comment: Which Coral product are you working with? Please share more details of the issue.

Comment: I'm using the USB Accelerator.

Comment: Can you share the output of uname -a ?